# flavour : override package name

Tags: android, android-productflavors

I had a project with this package name : `applicationId 'com.safa.auditzanjan'`
Now I have created a flavour into other same project and I have added those project into this project. this new package name's project is:`applicationId "com.safa.auditkhoramabad"`.
how could I set older package Name to this flavour?Thats mean I want to do override `com.safa.auditkhoramabad` for my new flavour to `com.safa.auditzanjan`?

***EDIT***********

this is my Independent gradle config project:

```
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.safa.auditzanjan'
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 56
    versionName '1.8.56'
}
dexOptions {
    jumboMode = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        versionNameSuffix '-debug'
    }
}
productFlavors {
    main {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.SigningConfig1
    }
    ts {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.SigningConfig1
        applicationIdSuffix ".ts"
        versionNameSuffix "-ts"
    }
}
```

this is flavour gradle config:

```
        zanjan {
        applicationId 'com.safa.auditzanjan'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.SigningConfig1
        applicationIdSuffix ".zanjan"
        versionNameSuffix "-zanjan"
        versionCode 56
        versionName '1.8.56'
        resValue( "string", "app_name", "ممیزی زنجان")
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like following

```
productFlavors {

    flavor1 {
        applicationId "com.safa.auditzanjan"

    }


    flavor2 {
        applicationId "com.safa.auditkhoramabad"

    }
```

Comment: It is not work. when I have installed last app from `'com.safa.auditzanjan' and new app from new flavour `applicationId "com.safa.auditzanjan"` on my mobile , this app twice installed into my phone whereas must be installed just one application.

Comment: hmm, strange....the above is what I'm doing in app here right now.  How are you building/running app....if in AS, are you selecting different build variant?  If building from gradle, are you using different tasks e.g. `assembleFlavor1Debug` ?

Comment: for both them I've just selected `Build APK` from Build menu

Comment: You'll need to change build variant you're using to select between the different build flavors.